# Visual Studio 2019 -How can I go step-by-step while debugging?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, debugging

I put a breakpoint on a line in my code, then I want to go step by step and getting into the code. I think it used to be F8 but it looks like they changed. Does anyone knows about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use F11 to step into and F10 to step over

Comment: @JayV VS2019 Step Into = F8

Comment: Personally I just type Stop in code where I want it to stop, then continue through the stop points.

Comment: @Mr.Tripodi Not on my installation of VS2019. I have the Visual C# 2005 mappings

Comment: @JayV interesting, I dont even know what F11 does, yet...

Comment: F11 and F8 are both steping into

Comment: And for an official reference [Keyboard shortcuts for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/tips-and-tricks-for-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

Comment: You can customize those keys as you please. I think everybody does.

Comment: @JayV thank u guys. and plus how can I pop the window "load" . I was looking on yt and they have a window called load that shows the value of each row in the code.

Comment: @luk Can you give us the Url of the video to get an idea what you are talking about, please?

Comment: @JayV https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0vDKXIq_9A&t=207s
there you go....and it is "Local" I am sorry...

Comment: Most of those windows (at the bottom of the main VS app) open up when you start debugging. If you find that one is missing (or close it by accident) you can get them back from the menu Debug -> Windows

Comment: @JayV I think I closed by accident. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what your problem might be exactly, but check the `Debug` tab for `Step x` options, next to them are their respective keyboard shortcuts.